# tsconfig's outDir vs esbuild's outdir

Tags: typescript, npm, tsconfig, esbuild

What is the difference between tsconfig's `outDir` vs esbuild's `outdir`? Seems like the do the same thing. esbuild supposedly detects the tsconfig, so which should I use? This is for a TypeScript library on npm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Only certain features](https://esbuild.github.io/content-types/#tsconfig-json) of `tsconfig.json` are used by esbuild:

> esbuild currently only inspects the following fields in tsconfig.json files:
>
> - `alwaysStrict`
> - `baseUrl`
> - `extends`
> - `importsNotUsedAsValues`
> - `jsx`
> - `jsxFactory`
> - `jsxFragmentFactory`
> - `jsxImportSource`
> - `paths`
> - `preserveValueImports`
> - `target`
> - `useDefineForClassFields`

Therefore you should use esbuild's `outdir`, the `outDir` configuration in `tsfonfig.json` will have no effect.